# How to understand robot.txt file codes

Tags: robots.txt

hy, every body, 
is there anyone that can help me to understand the code
i want to know about what the meaning or below code, i am confusing to understand this code in `robot.txt` file.

```
Disallow: /?/*
in robot.txt
```

Comment: It's a secret code; once deciphered it will output [this link](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=robots.txt&oq=robots.txt&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l4.1455j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

This is robots excllusion protocol.This file is to give instructions about their site to web robots and

```
"Disallow: /"
```

tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

You will find more info [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Answer (score 0):

This robots.txt file is mainly used for the SEO purpose,
by including this file, you can provide URLs which you don't want to visit for SEO.
So basically, Which URLs you don't want to put on for SEO, just write that URLs in this file, so it will exclude those URLs from the SEO, google analytic